# How can I fix the Error "history resample interval is too short, cannot uses it to resample!!" in Android Studio (with Java)?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, dialog

I'm trying to build an Dialog in android studios with Java.
But the problem is, that however I try it the Error
"D/InputTransport: history resample interval is too short, cannot uses it to resample!!"
appears.
I already searched for a solution, but I found nothing similar.
I also tried it with another mobile phone, but it didn't work as well.
Here is my source-text:

```
public void add(View view){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("title");
        alertDialog.setMessage("text");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

The method "add" is opened by a button.
I would be happy about every help!

Comment: i highly doubt the logs you've posted are relevant to the code you have here. are you sure your logcat is set to filter for the selected application only ?

Comment: First I looked at "run", but in Logcat it's the same (with filter). I also think it must be this error, because it only appears, when I click the button.